# Windows adding additional keyboard languages by itself

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, keyboard-layout, language

I have this really annoying problem with Win7 adding random keyboard language layouts...
I am using Swedish and Japanese since I live in japan and i only use these two (As I can write all the english characters without problem on the swedish keyboard)

But every now and again when i toggle in between them with "Alt+Left Shift" There's a third or sometimes even a FOURTH new language in the list.. When i open the settings they are NOT, i repeat, NOT listed in there. However when i press the shortcut to switch inbeween them they are selscted..

I wish to solve this as it is VERY annoying when i for example have two conversations, in japanese and english/swedish..

If anyone has any idea, lemme know!

Comment: Which language is the fourth one? Isn't that just an alternative method of entering Japanese charecters?

Answer (score 0):

I have had exactly same problem. It was seemed to be caused by newly installed software. It can be .Net Frameworks or anthing else that might use English as default language. Try to uninstall programs that you installed right before the problem occured. If that does not help, try to restore the system to the previous state.

**Edit**

Also there is a clever solution that I just came up with. If you delete swedish from the list and then add English or whichever language is coming up and change the keyboard layout to the Swedish one and then see which layout will that other language use by default (for example Enlgish might have USA layout) and add it to the list of keyboards. Then move Swedish to the top of the list of available languages and enjoy the fix.

Answer (score 0):

Looking for answers on how to fix this via automation: [Where does Windows 7 store input languages that it switches between](https://superuser.com/questions/708544/where-does-windows-7-store-input-languages-that-it-switches-between).

So far, brute force method: Autohotkey script. This is not optimal but it gets the job done:

```
^+!l::
Run, Control input.dll
Sleep, 1000
Send {Tab}{Tab}
Sleep, 100
Send {Enter}
Sleep, 1000
Send e
Sleep, 100
Send {Down}{Down}{Down}{Down}{Down}{Down}{Down}{Down}{Down}{Down}{Down}{Down}{Down}
Sleep, 100
Send {Right}{Down}{Right}US{Space}{Enter}
Sleep, 100
Send {Tab}{Tab}{Tab}
Sleep, 100
Send {Enter}
Sleep, 1000
Send {Tab}{PgDn}{PgDn}{PgDn}
Send {Tab}{Tab}{Enter}
Sleep, 100
Send A
Sleep, 100
Send {Enter}
return
```

Basically you press Ctrl+Shift+Alt+L when you start getting the bug and it fixes it - adds English (US) and removes it. May need tweaking around the wait values, and also maybe with the amount of Down's - I don't know if language list is the same on every computer (maybe it changes with time too).

Answer (score 0):

I have a better solution than the Autohotkey one. Create a `.bat` file with the following:

```
control intl.cpl,, /f:"LangAdd.xml"
control intl.cpl,, /f:"LangRemove.xml"
```

and corresponding xml files with the following:

```
<gs:GlobalizationServices xmlns:gs="urn:longhornGlobalizationUnattend">
<gs:UserList>
<gs:User UserID="Current"/> 
</gs:UserList>
<gs:InputPreferences> 
<gs:InputLanguageID Action="add" ID="0409:00000409"/> 
</gs:InputPreferences> 
</gs:GlobalizationServices>
```

and

```
<gs:GlobalizationServices xmlns:gs="urn:longhornGlobalizationUnattend">
<gs:UserList>
<gs:User UserID="Current"/> 
</gs:UserList>
<gs:InputPreferences> 
<gs:InputLanguageID Action="remove" ID="0409:00000409"/> 
</gs:InputPreferences> 
</gs:GlobalizationServices>
```

409 is the language for en-US. Change it to the offending language code [from this list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh361638(v=office.14).aspx). You can assign a keyboard shortcut to a shortcut to the bat file if you want, also choose Run: Minimized in shortcut preferences to avoid the flashing window.