# Windows 10 adds languages by itself

Tags: windows-10, language

I have 2 language layouts selected: ENG(US) and SLK(QWERTY) in
`Control Panel\Clock, Language and Region\Language`
Sometimes, ENG and ENG(US) get added.

I have no Idea how to stop it and it's VERY annoying.

I found answer to [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/448794/windows-adding-additional-keyboard-languages-by-itself), but I have no idea what both answers mean.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keyboard language keeps changing in Windows 10](http://superuser.com/questions/976947/keyboard-language-keeps-changing-in-windows-10)

Comment: No, The keyboard layout keeps switching between the 2 selected. On my PC, there are 2 different keyboard layouts which I have not selected, nor I can found any way to deselect them. 
Only place where I can see those languages is that popup that you get when you press `win` + `space`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,  this is bug. You need manually remove the extra lang when it happens.

Comment: It might be worth elaborating on the general steps OP may want to take to do this.

Comment: There was no way of manually removing the languages, as stated here: https://superuser.com/questions/1066597/windows-10-adds-languages-by-itself/1498208#comment1501561_1066597

The issue resolved itself with a Windows update

Comment: Not resolved as of June 2020. I receive all updates and it still keeps adding languages.